# Find upper right element in 2D vector array

Tags: c, sorting

I have an array of 9 vectors which make up a 3x3 dot matrix.
Now I want to find the most "upper left" (marked with `O`) and most "upper right" (marked `D`) element.
The whole thing is not rectangular and the array is not sorted. So it might look like this:

```
array[0] x= 771 y=324
array[1] x= 968 y=323
array[2] x= 868 y= 397
array[3] x= 1065 y= 368
array[4] x= 1164 y= 326
array[5] x= 768 y= 470
array[6] x= 966 y= 471
array[7] x= 1000 y= 452
array[8] x= 1165 y= 472

O----x----D
|    |    |
|    |    |
x----x----x
|    |    |
|    |    |
x----x----x
```

I dont really have a clue where to start from here. Do I compare x and y at the same time?

```
   FindD(int& x, int& y)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++)
        {
          if(i != j)
          {

            //compare the array elements
          }

        }
      }
    }

FindO(int& x, int& y)
```

EDIT: I should point out that the points are not arbitrary placed on the plane. They always appear in the 3x3 pattern but the distances between the points differ by some pixels. Also, the whole pattern might be placed a little rotatet.
Thats actually why I want to find the most upper right and left element. To get the rotation angle.

Comment: Try to find min x, max y and max x. The answer would be (min x,max y) and  (max x, max y).

Comment: @tzippy What is the most left upper point between this two points {  1, 1 } and { 2, 2 }?

Comment: What is the definition of "most upper right".

Comment: At least, it your example, what would be O and D?

Comment: You have 9 points *arbitrary placed* in the plane, *not as in your illustration*. It is then difficult to *generally* define which of them is *the most upper left* and *the most upper right*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta D would be array[4] and O would be array[0]

Comment: @tzippy  please put all relevant information __into__ your question

Comment: That's not valid C code! And there is no 2D array.

Comment: @Olaf "2D vector array" here, should be parsed as "an array of 2D coordinates"...

Comment: I already got that. You still don't show a 2D array in the incomplete snippet. You might read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

```
O----x----D
|    |    |
|    |    |
T----x----T
|    |    |
|    |    |
x----x----x
```

Assuming that "a little rotated" means the points marked `T` above can not have higher y-values than those you're looking for and assuming your coordinates start in the lower left corner and have increasing y-values upwards and increasing x-values towards the right:

Find the three points with the highest y-values, the one with the lowest x-value of those is the left one.

Comment: The assumption is correct. And wow, I really did not think of that. I only have to find the most upper 3 points and then take the one with the hightest and lowest x value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a function for calculating min and a function for calculating max of an array. Passing all x points array and y points array, find min x, max y and max x. The answer would be `(min x,max y)`and`(max x, max y).`

Answer (score 0):

I would use simple coordinate operations to define the *upper left* and *upper right points*. Based on you edit and comments, I would define:

- upper left point has minimum value for x+y
- upper right point has miminum value for x-y

The problem becomes then a simple selection of min/max in an array.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are. You can use your own predicates to find any point.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Point
{ 
    int x;
    int y;
};


int upper_right(  struct Point a, struct Point b )
{
    return ( b.x < a.x ) || ( !( a.x < b.x ) && ( b.y < a.y ) );
}

int upper_left(  struct Point a, struct Point b )
{
    return ( a.x < b.x ) || ( !( b.x < a.x ) && ( b.y < a.y ) );
}

struct Point * max_element( const struct Point *a, 
                            size_t n, 
                            int predicate( struct Point, struct Point ) )
{
    const struct Point *max = a;

    if ( n )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( predicate( a[i], *max ) ) max = a + i;
        }
    }

    return ( struct Point * )max;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Point a[] =
    {
        {  771, 324 },
        {  968, 323 },
        {  868, 397 },
        { 1065, 368 },
        { 1164, 326 },
        {  768, 470 },
        {  966, 471 },
        { 1000, 452 },
        { 1165, 472 }
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( * a );

    struct Point *max = max_element( a, N, upper_left );

    printf( "The upper left point is { %d, %d }\n", max->x, max->y );

    max = max_element( a, N, upper_right );

    printf( "The upper right point is { %d, %d }\n", max->x, max->y );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The upper left point is { 768, 470 }
The upper right point is { 1165, 472 }
```